# How to fill color on triangle

Tags: java, geometry, drawing

I draw a triangle using line. How can I fill color on it? So far I can only success color the line but not fill the color.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        int k=0;
        for (j=0 ; j < numOfLines; j++){    // the values of numOfLines retrieved from other method.
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(x[k], x[k+1], x[k+2], x[k+3]);
        k = k+4;  //index files
        }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make a [`Polygon`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) from the vertices and fill that instead, by calling [`fillPolygon(...)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillPolygon(java.awt.Polygon)):

```
// A simple triangle.
x[0]=100; x[1]=150; x[2]=50;
y[0]=100; y[1]=150; y[2]=150;
n = 3;

Polygon p = new Polygon(x, y, n);  // This polygon represents a triangle with the above
                                   //   vertices.

g.fillPolygon(p);     // Fills the triangle above.
```

Comment: how do you set the color to fill the triangle with?

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the vertices of your polygon (in this case, a triangle) and pass to `fillPolygon():`

```
  public void paint(Graphics g) 
  {
    int xpoints[] = {25, 145, 25, 145, 25};
    int ypoints[] = {25, 25, 145, 145, 25};
    int npoints = 5;

    g.fillPolygon(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks....but is that mean triangle drawn using Lines cannot be filled with color?

Comment: @Jessy: the intersection of the lines (i.e. the vertices) are the points you require.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         super.paintComponents(g);

      int x[] = {1,2,3};
      int y[] = {4,5,6};
      int npoints = x.length;//or y.length

      g.drawPolygon(x, y, npoints);//draws polygon outline
      g.fillPolygon(x, y, npoints);//paints a polygon

}
```