# Java SolidBrush and Pen like in C#

Tags: java, graphics, drawing

I have trouble with Java graphics. In C# I'm using pen and solidbrush but what can I use in Java to
create or to fill polygon? I want to brush some part of matrix,in C# I'm using this code

```
public void Draw( Graphics oGraph)
{
    Pen blackpen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);


    Point[] tmpPoints = (Point[]) thePoints.Clone();

    for(int i=0;i<iNumPoints;i++)
    {
        tmpPoints[i].X += iPosX;
        tmpPoints[i].Y += iPosY;
    }


    oGraph.DrawPolygon(blackpen, tmpPoints);
    oGraph.FillPolygon(piecebrush, tmpPoints, FillMode.Winding);

    blackpen.Dispose();
}
```

and its working in C#,but in java it wont work. What code should I use in java to create that polygon if in java graphics I need drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints).

Java code that can help

```
    private int[][] iMatrix;
    private Point[] thePoints;
    private int     iNumPoints;
    private Graphics g;


    public figura()
    {
        iMatrix = new int[3][3];
    }
    public void NapraviFiguru(int oblik)
    {
        switch(oblik)
        {
            case 1:
                iMatrix[0][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[2][0] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[2][1] = 0;


                iMatrix[0][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[1][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][2] = 0;

                g.setColor(Color.blue);

                break;
            case 2:
                iMatrix[0][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[2][0] = 1;

                iMatrix[0][1] = 0;
                iMatrix[1][1] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][1] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[1][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][2] = 0;

                g.setColor(Color.green);
                break;
            case 3:
                iMatrix[0][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][0] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][0] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[2][1] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[1][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][2] = 0;


                g.setColor(Color.yellow);

                break;
            case 4:
                iMatrix[0][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[2][0] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][1] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][1] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][2] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][2] = 0;

                g.setColor(Color.red);

                break;
            case 5:
                iMatrix[0][0] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][0] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][0] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][1] = 1;
                iMatrix[1][1] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][1] = 0;

                iMatrix[0][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[1][2] = 0;
                iMatrix[2][2] = 0;

                g.setColor(Color.pink);

                break;
        }
        CreatePoints();
    }

    private void CreatePoints()
    {

        final int _RECTSIZE_ = 20;

        Point[] tmpPoints = new Point[100];
        int iPoints = 0, i = 0, j = 0;

        iNumPoints = 0;

        Point[] tmpPoints2 = new Point[36];

        for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(iMatrix[j][i] == 0)
                {
                    if(j != 0)
                    {
                        if(iMatrix[j-1][i] == 1)
                        {
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x  = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                            iPoints++;

                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            iPoints++;
                        }
                    }

                    if(j != 2)
                    {
                        if(iMatrix[j+1][i] == 1)
                        {
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_)+_RECTSIZE_;
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                            iPoints++;

                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            iPoints++;
                        }
                    }

                    if(i != 0)
                    {
                        if(iMatrix[j][i-1] == 1)
                        {
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                            iPoints++;

                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                            iPoints++;
                        }
                    }

                    if(i != 2)
                    {
                        if(iMatrix[j][i+1] == 1)
                        {
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_)+_RECTSIZE_;
                            iPoints++;

                            tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                            iPoints++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(j == 0)
                {
                    if(iMatrix[j][i] == 1)
                    {
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                        iPoints++;

                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        iPoints++;
                    }
                }

                if(j == 2)
                {
                    if(iMatrix[j][i] == 1)
                    {
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                        iPoints++;

                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        iPoints++;
                    }
                }

                if(i == 0)
                {
                    if(iMatrix[j][i] == 1)
                    {
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                        iPoints++;

                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_)+_RECTSIZE_;
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_);
                        iPoints++;
                    }
                }

                if(i == 2)
                {
                    if(iMatrix[j][i] == 1)
                    {
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_);
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        iPoints++;

                        tmpPoints[iPoints].x = (j * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        tmpPoints[iPoints].y = (i * _RECTSIZE_) + _RECTSIZE_;
                        iPoints++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

and after that I'm using

```
public void Paint( Graphics Graph)
    {


        Point[] tmpPoints = (Point[]) thePoints.clone();

        for(int i=0;i<iNumPoints;i++)
        {
            tmpPoints[i].x += iPosX;
            tmpPoints[i].y += iPosY;
        }

        Graph.DrawPolygon(tmpPoints,iNumPoints);
        Graph.FillPolygon(piecebrush, tmpPoints);

        blackpen.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please give us your implementation in Java!

Comment: Do you have some java code to show? See this dor example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675878/how-to-fill-color-on-triangle

Comment: Well,the code in java is almost the same,I'm trying to create like in C#,with tmpPoints.

Comment: Perhaps we are not being 100% clear - please edit your question and paste your current Java implementation there (never mind that it's not working).