# Draw a down triangle shape

Tags: java, graphics, paint, jfreechart

I am trying to draw down triangles in my GanttRenderer class in JFreeChart. I can get the shape from the Shape Utilities:

```
Shape triangle = ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(4.0f);
```

How do I draw the shape at the correct location and set the dimension parameters?

```
public class Renderer extends GanttRenderer {

private final TaskSeriesCollection model;

public Renderer(TaskSeriesCollection model) {
    this.model = model;
}
@Override
protected void drawTasks(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state, Rectangle2D dataArea, CategoryPlot plot, CategoryAxis domainAxis,
        ValueAxis rangeAxis, GanttCategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column) {   

        /*Some other code here*/

            Shape triangle = ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(4.0f);
//              Rectangle2D triangleContainer = triangle.getBounds2D();
//              triangleContainer.setRect(subtaskStartTranslated, rectYAxisStart, rectBreadth, rectBreadth);

            g2.setPaint(new Color(255,0,0));
            g2.draw(triangle);

        /*Some other code here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it with this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/675878/how-to-fill-color-on-triangle

Comment: Do not pass the TaskSeriesCollection to the renderer via the constructor. It is provided as parameter dataset in the the drawTasks method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a translated shape of your original shape as follows:

```
Shape downTriangle = ShapeUtils.createTranslatedShape(ShapeUtils.createDownTriangle(sizeFactor), sizeFactor, sizeFactor);
```